# Исключить повторы из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

`alert(provider_name)` выводит:

> Билайн Билайн Билайн Мегафон Мегафон МТС

Нужно оставить:

> Билайн Мегафон МТС

**Код JavaScript:**

```
var response_length = resp[country_size].providers.length;
for(i = 0; i < response_length; i++) {
 var provider_name = resp[country_size].providers[i].name;
 alert(provider_name);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тот же вопрос на стэке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486479/javascript-array-unique).
Пример оттуда же:

```
var arrayUnique = function(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
        if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []);
};
```